# Reopened PyGtk window is empty

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, hide, glade

I am working with Glade to make a simple GUI application using PyGTK. I have two windows, one only showing up when a button is pressed.

```
    def on_preview_clicked(self, widget):
           print "You clicked the Preview button"
           prev = self.builder.get_object("previewWindow")
           prev.show()
```

The window is working fine, but if I close it, and try to open it again, it becomes empty.
I found on google that it may be because the window I am referring to was "destroyed", so I made the window hide instead.

```
    def hide_preview(self, widget):
            print "Hide it!"
            prev = self.builder.get_object("previewWindow")
            prev.hide()
            return True
```

This did nothing, the window still comes up empty the second time around.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you create a minimal testcase that exhibits this problem? Maybe you're running into [this problem](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq10.013.htp) or something, but it's hard to say without more info. In general, doing hide() and show() should allow the widgets to remain in your window.

Answer (score 0):

Without a working testcase of this, it's difficult to be sure, but try changing it from `show()` to `show_all()`, to be sure that all the child widgets of the window are shown as well.

Comment: I will try this as son as I get of work. If it dose not work I will post a full example.